# Get Workflow Status Programmatically in SharePoint Using Client Side Object Model JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, workflow, csom

I am trying to monitor the status of workflows using JavaScript in the SharePoint Farm.

List A: 
Number of Completed:
In Progress: 
Error occurred:

List B:
...

Answer (score 0):

**Get Workflow status via CSOM**

```
function getWorkflowStatus(listTitle,listItemId,workflowTitle, success,error)
{
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
  var listItem = list.getItemById(listItemId);   
  context.load(listItem);
  context.executeQueryAsync(
     function() {
       var workflowStatusField = listItem.get_parentList().get_fields().getByTitle(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field
       var workflowStatusValue = listItem.get_item(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field value
       success(workflowStatusValue); 
     },
     error
  );
}



//Example: check whether workflow has been completed for a List Item
var listTitle = 'Pages';
var listItemId = 1;
var workflowTitle = 'Approval';
getWorkflowStatus(listTitle,listItemId,workflowTitle,function(status){
   if(status == 5){  
       console.log('Approval is completed');
   } 
},
function(sender,args){
   console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

https://ravichandran.blog/2016/02/12/get-workflow-status-programmatically-in-sharepoint-using-client-side-object-model-c/